# C# SSIS Script to pick up yesterdays file

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to run a script that picks up a file based on file name which has a date stamp in the file name but I've run into a bit of a blocker.

So far I've got the following

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::VarFolderPath"].Value.ToString());

        FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            if (file.FullName == "Call_Stat_V5_20150325.csv"
            {
                    dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value = file.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I'm having trouble making the end part of that file name dynamic. So everyday a new file will drop in to the folder location with a new date appended to the end. How would I go about go about making it dynamic and looking for yesterdays file?

The file prefix and file extension will never change, just the date parameter.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Comment: You don't have to use a script. An SSIS Expression will work just as well. If you clean the file up after processing, you don't even have to worry about calculating yesterday's date. Just use a ForEach file enumerator and look for anything called `Call_Stat_V5*.csv`

Comment: The reason why I'm using a date parameter is that each file gets loaded into a database once. So instead of recreating everyday, it will just be a daily file load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;
string d = t.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

string fileName = "Call_Stat_V5" + d + ".csv";

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    if (file.FullName == fileName)
    {
          dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value = file.ToString();
    }
}
```

You are taking current date with first line and remove one day from it. After that you making current to string and format the string like this `"yyyyMMdd"`.
You need to create fileName string and you have your check.